# How can I open a bootstrap modal window popup instead of opening it in a new window?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to have a modal window popup listing off any validation errors to the user when they submit the form.  With my current code, the window is opening as a completely new view instead of a modal window.  How can I get this window to overlap the form's view instead of opening an entirely new view?

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Daily(Daily dailyReport)
{
    var dr = new ReportDaily();
    var rc = new ReportDailyCriteria();
    dr.Preview(rc, IntPtr.Zero, out Notification notification);
    if (notification.HasErrors) {
        var error = new Errors();
        string errorString = notification.GetConcatenatedErrorMessage(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
        error.ErrorList = errorString;
        return PartialView("_ErrorsModal", error);
    }
    return View(dailyReport);
}
```

**Partial View**

```
@model Test.Areas.Reports.Models.Errors
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="errorsModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title float-left">Error List</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label>Errors: @Model.ErrorList</label>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. As far as I understand you are posting your form to controller action as full post back. Instead, you need to send it as `ajax` post, this will give you flexibility working with the response.
2. I would recommend to render your modal on the initial page load and then working only with `JSON` when receiving result from controller. It will eliminate complex parsing logic of response (figuring out if it is a partial view or something else for proper further action).

So render your partial view on the main view (remove `Errors: @Model.ErrorList` from partial view and leave label empty as you don't need that anymore):

```
@Html.Partial("_ErrorsModal")
```

Your controller action that will return `Json`:

```
    [HttpPost]  
    public IActionResult Daily(Daily dailyReport)  
    {  
        var dr = new ReportDaily();
        var rc = new ReportDailyCriteria();
        dr.Preview(rc, IntPtr.Zero, out Notification notification);
        if (notification.HasErrors) 
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                success = false,
                message = notification.GetConcatenatedErrorMessage(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine)
            });
        }

        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

And your `ajax` call when you post the form:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify($('#your_form_id').serializeArray().reduce(function(m,o){ m[o.name] = o.value; return m;}, {})),
        url: 'http://your_website/your_controller/Daily',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.success){
                //your actions when validation successful...
            } else {
                $('#errorsModal .modal-body label').html(data.message);
                $('#errorsModal').modal('toggle');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: After implementing your code and submitting the form, it redirects to an all white page with the text: `{"success":false,"message":"Must select a payment Source, County and/or Municipal.\r\n\r\nMust select at least one payment type.\r\n\r\nMust select at least one user.\r\n\r\n"}`

Comment: most of all you are still submitting your form as full post back. show us how you submitting your form. it should be a simple button (not type=submit) with `onclick` function where should be `ajax` call from my answer